# Where can I find a list of German nouns with their articles?

Tags: computational-linguistics, german, resource-request, vocabulary

I am working on some linguistic software. The whole functionality is already there, the only thing that is missing is a good vocabulary to test it with. 
Of course there is no way to create a decent vocabulary manually, so I want to enlarge it automatically.

What I need is a list of German nouns with their articles (or let's say list of nouns "annotated" with gender), preferably the most frequent ones, or grouped by topics. Yet it's not a must.

At this point I am only interested in nouns.

I would be really thankful for any tips or ideas.

Comment: hmmm... ever heard of dictionaries?

Comment: @fdb Have fun typing a couple hundred or thousand words from a dictionary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a similar question on the German language SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7386):

- ["Greg's German
  nouns"](http://www.byki.com/lists/german/greg%27s-german-nouns-part-1.html) - a list of 1000 German nouns including articles and translations to English. You can just copy the HTML table into an excel table by
  holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while selecting. The format "der Gebrauch, e"
  requires some editing to extract only the noun and their article, but
  that is easily doable in a few seconds via regular expressions find
  and replace or something similar.
- [A nicer version of the
  above](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZonFtimNPQM0sI4rAwwHSG9tQHv2z-NET-Zkw69VtFY/edit#gid=1994324564)
  by SE user Tinjo. I think it's the same as the same set of words, but
  the copying into a table is already done.
- The download link ["1000 German
  Nouns"](https://germanwordlist.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/1000-german-nouns6.xlsx)
  on the Wordpress site
  ["germanwordlist"](https://germanwordlist.wordpress.com/). It's a list of 1286 words in a similar format as the above links; again, the format requires some simple editing to remove the additional information on the plural forms, but the words themselves should serve your purpose.

Comment: Could you make the links a bit more meaningful? For example, avoid "this" or "here" in links, You could link the title of the question or the "title" of what the link is about. Also a bit of context of what each link is about would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Alenanno Sure. Is it okay now?

Comment: That's really really helpul.
Thank's a lot!!! Makes me sad, that i cannot vote yet :D